# API call from Call of Duty API in R - authentication problem

Tags: r, node.js, api, authentication

I am trying to call the stats of a list of players from the call of duty API. This API requires firstly the login in website https://profile.callofduty.com/cod/login. Once logged in, the user can see the stats of a player using the call-of-duty API. For example, the stats of the streamer **savyultras90** from Warzone can be seen through the following link: https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/mw/platform/psn/gamer/savyultras90/profile/type/wz.

If I log in from the website and try to see the stats of a player and the related json, I am able to do via browser. However, this doesn't seem straightforward in R.

I try to log in using the `GET` function from `httr` package as follows

```
respo <- GET('https://profile.callofduty.com/cod/login', authenticate('USER', 'PWD'))
```

But when I try to have access to the api and download the JSON file using the function `fromJSON` from the package `jsonlite` as follows

```
data <- fromJSON('https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/mw/platform/psn/gamer/savyultras90/profile/type/wz')
```

I get the error message "Not permitted: not authenticated".

How can I authenticate in one website and stay logged in to call from the API which relies on that authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing I've recently had to develop a PHP API for Warzone, I might be able to guide you in the right direction on how to handle this. But first a few remarks:

- You need to authenticate each user individually with the appropriate platform if you want to request that player's data
- There is a throttle limit on the amount of API requests
- **The API of Call of Duty is under strict usage guidelines and should only be used by registered partners. Making usage of the API could result in claims and eventually lawsuits:** [link](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2021-03-27-creators-of-hugely-popular-sbmm-warzone-website-say-activision-has-ordered-them-to-shut-down-by-monday)
- There is no public documentation of the API and the API has changed in the past, breaking several 3rd party tools.

Nevertheless, the process involves several steps as described below:

**Register the device making the call**

https://profile.callofduty.com/cod/mapp/registerDevice

with a json body in the form of `{"deviceId":"INSERT_ID_HERE"}`
This will return a response with the authHeader which we will use for as Token in the next calls

**Login with Activision credentials**

https://profile.callofduty.com/cod/mapp/login

Set the following headers:

```
Authorization: "INSERT_AUTHHEADER_HERE"
x_cod_device_id: "INSERT_PREVIOUSLY_USED_DEVICEID_HERE"
```

This in terms will generate a dataset where we will save the following data from:
rtkn, ACT_SSO_COOKIE and atkn.

**Make the wanted API call for data**

We have all the data now required to make the API call.

For each request we will submit 3 headers:

1. Authorization: "INSERT_AUTHHEADER_HERE"
2. x_cod_device_id: "INSERT_PREVIOUSLY_USED_DEVICEID_HERE"
3. Cookie: `ACT_SSO_LOCALE=en_GB;country=GB;API_CSRF_TOKEN=**GENERATE_CSRF_TOKEN**;rtkn=**RTKN_HERE**;ACT_SSO_COOKIE=**ACT_SSO_COOKIE_HERE**;atkn=**ATKN_HERE**`

For more reference, you can always look through a [Python library](https://pypi.org/project/callofduty.py/) or [NodeJS library](https://github.com/Lierrmm/Node-CallOfDuty) which succesfully implemented the API.

Comment: If the login step isn't working for anyone attempting this, it's because the auth header needs to be ```Authorization: "bearer AUTHHEADER_TOKEN"```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this yesterday but finally made some progress. The issue is that you have to obtain an authentication token. The steps can be followed here: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7896975/SW7aXSo5#a37a2e5b-84bb-441d-b978-0fd8d42ffd29 but not available in R though.

My code works at first, as long as you don't authenticate again (still trying to figure out why). Basically what I did was to translate the steps in the link and extracted the content in the response from GET:

```
# Get token ---------------------------------------------------------------

resp <- GET('https://profile.callofduty.com/cod/login')
cookies = c(
  'XSRF-TOKEN' = resp$cookies$value[1]
  ,'new_SiteId' = resp$cookies$value[2]
  ,'comid' = resp$cookies$value[3]
  ,'bm_sz' = resp$cookies$value[4]
  ,'_abck' = resp$cookies$value[5]
  # ,'ACT_SSO_COOKIE' = resp$cookies$value[6]
  # ,'ACT_SSO_COOKIE_EXPIRY' = resp$cookies$value[7]
  # ,'atkn' = resp$cookies$value[8]
  # ,'ACT_SSO_REMEMBER_ME' = resp$cookies$value[9]
  # ,'ACT_SSO_EVENT' = resp$cookies$value[10]
  # ,'pgacct' = resp$cookies$value[11]
  # ,'CRM_BLOB' = resp$cookies$value[12]
  # ,'tfa_enrollment_seen' = resp$cookies$value[13]
)

headers = c(
  
)

params = list(
  `new_SiteId` = 'cod',
  `username` = 'USER',
  `password` = 'PWD',
  `remember_me` = 'true',
  `_csrf` = resp$cookies$value[1]
)

# Authenticate ------------------------------------------------------------

resp_post <- POST('https://profile.callofduty.com/do_login?new_SiteId=cod',
                  httr::add_headers(.headers=headers),
                  query = params,
                  httr::set_cookies(.cookies = cookies))


cookies = c(
  'XSRF-TOKEN' = resp_post$cookies$value[1]
  ,'new_SiteId' = resp_post$cookies$value[2]
  ,'comid' = resp_post$cookies$value[3]
  ,'bm_sz' = resp_post$cookies$value[4]
  ,'_abck' = resp_post$cookies$value[5]
  ,'ACT_SSO_COOKIE' = resp_post$cookies$value[6]
  ,'ACT_SSO_COOKIE_EXPIRY' = resp_post$cookies$value[7]
  ,'atkn' = resp_post$cookies$value[8]
  ,'ACT_SSO_REMEMBER_ME' = resp_post$cookies$value[9]
  ,'ACT_SSO_EVENT' = resp_post$cookies$value[10]
  ,'pgacct' = resp_post$cookies$value[11]
  ,'CRM_BLOB' = resp_post$cookies$value[12]
  ,'tfa_enrollment_seen' = resp_post$cookies$value[13]
)

headers = c(
  
)

params = list(
  `new_SiteId` = 'cod',
  `username` = 'USER',
  `password` = 'PWD',
  `remember_me` = 'true',
  `_csrf` = resp_post$cookies$value[1]
)

# Get data:

  resp_psn <- httr::GET(url = 'https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/mw/platform/psn/gamer/savyultras90/profile/type/wz',
                        httr::add_headers(.headers=headers),
                        query = params,
                        httr::set_cookies(.cookies = cookies))

resp_psn_json <- content(resp_psn)
```

Let me know if you've already managed to resolve this!